# Docker web app on Azure Web App for Container

Tags: docker, nginx, containers, azure-container-service, azure-webapps

I am new to both docker and azure container services. I am trying to deploy a docker web app in the Azure Web App for Containers as single container instance. I am using the azure-vote-front image provided [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-voting-app-redis).  I followed the steps provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-docker) after tagging and pushing the docker image in an Azure container register.

But after deploying the web app and navigating to the web url, all it shows is 
**502 Bad Gateway**
with **nginx/1.15.8** mentioned below. Is there addtional configuration, I need to mention in any file or configure anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your issue, you misunderstand the image `azure-vote-front`. You can the docker-compose.yaml file in the Github link your provide, it creates the `azure-vote-front` image, but it also needs the database Redis. So it's not a single container instance, it's the multiple containers.

You can need to create the image `azure-vote-front` and push it to the Azure Container Registry. Also does the image `Redis`. Then you can change the `docker-compose.yaml` file like this:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  azure-vote-back:
    image: youracrname.azurecr.io/redis
    container_name: azure-vote-back
    ports:
        - "6379:6379"

  azure-vote-front:
    image: youracrname.azurecr.io/azure-vote-front
    container_name: azure-vote-front
    environment:
      REDIS: azure-vote-back
    ports:
        - "80:80"
```

And set the ACR credential with the command here:

```
az webapp config container set -g group_name -n app_name --docker-registry-server-url youracrname.azurecr.io --docker-registry-server-user acr_username --docker-registry-server-password acr_password
```

Finally, wait for munites and then you can access the Web App. For more details, see the example [Create a multi-container (preview) app in Web App for Containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-multi-container-app).